# bitcoind getinfo or getbalance freeze

Tags: bitcoind

I am a bitcoin newbie. I am testing solo mining (I know it is not financial feasible in general). I installed bitcoind on Debian and it ran okay as far as I could tell. I've experienced a couple of problems. The size of the bitcoin data directory is still growing when I use:

```
du -ks .bitcoin/
```

I ran

```
./bitcoind getinfo
```

and got information like this:

```
{
    "version" : 80600,
    "protocolversion" : 70001,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 225436,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 9,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 4367876.00084220,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1389424771,
    "keypoolsize" : 103,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

When I ran

```
./bitcoind getbalance
```

I got 0.000000000

The problem is sometime,

```
./bitcoind getinfo
```

simply freeze and I have to use Ctrl-c to kill it.

Another problem is I cannot connect to bitcoind using

```
./minerd --url http://127.0.0.1:8332 --userpass username:password
```

The result I got is:

```
[2014-01-12 20:54:03] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2014-01-12 20:54:04] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2014-01-12 20:54:05] 2 miner threads started, using SHA256 'c' algorithm.
[2014-01-12 21:01:36] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500
[2014-01-12 21:01:36] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
[2014-01-12 21:02:15] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500
[2014-01-12 21:02:15] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
[2014-01-12 21:02:56] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500
[2014-01-12 21:02:56] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
[2014-01-12 21:03:35] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500
[2014-01-12 21:03:35] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

Again, I had to use Ctrl-c.

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this type of conf file works :

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=any_username
rpcpassword=any_password
```

if not then allow ip 127.0.0.1 in bitcoin.conf

```
rpcusername=your_usename
rpcpassword=your_password
allowip=127.0.0.1
allowport=8332
```

This may help, you may also try allowing ip 0.0.0.0 if both of the above does not works

Comment: Good advice and the likely answer, it should be noted that allowip need not be set for localhost or 127.0.0.1 (as it is allowed by default)